# How to automatically add jar files to android project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, jar

I am a never android developer. I'm currently developing a project which require a big number of jar files. It is difficult for me to add all of them manually.

I try to use maven but I found a lot of problems. 
Is there any other solution?

NB : I use eclipse IDE and I don't want to use android studio .

Comment: What do you mean 'automatically  add jar files'? A simple copy to 'lib' directory is all it takes.

Comment: like what maven do . If I have 100 jar files for example from different repositories  it is time consuming to add them by a simple copy  to' lib' directory

Answer (score -1):

You can use gradle / maven also with Eclipse. I hate maven for Android, it's impossibile to use very well. I suggest Gradle, because now is the default tool (perfectly integrated in Android Studio, but there is also a plugin for Eclipse).

For example, my gradle file is:

```
(...)

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    provided 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'

    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.2.3'
}
```

I really suggest to switch to Android Studio. I'm using this software since july and i think that is extremely better/stable than Eclipse for Android.

Comment: ok, this is not a complete build.gradle file. I posted here only the dependencies ;)